# Ubuntu 20.4 autoinstall user-data skip installing security updates

Tags: server, system-installation, security

everyone,
is it possible to disable the option of downloading and installing security updates on an Ubuntu installation? The installation takes a long time and is aborted with the message apt config resotre. I run my installation of Ubuntu with my user-data configuration.

The script subiquity/Install/install/postinstall/run_unattended_upgrades: runnig still 1hour

Comment: I found a couple of methods that effectively skip the updates at the end of an autoinstall.  https://askubuntu.com/a/1410679/376778

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will always install security updates by default and it will start the download of these updates while booted to the installer.  However, you do not have to wait for these security updates to be fully installed.  You can safely choose the option to reboot the system, any updates that have been downloaded will be saved, and the installation of security updates will be completed as part of the next daily job.

Answer (score 0):

During install, the source.list is read from /etc/apt inside squashfs filesystem. You can disable updates in sources.list and enabled it again at end of install.